# Binding a viewmodel's property to another's

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a main window coupled with a view model.This main window uses a usercontrol which also has its own viewmodel.

What I would like to achieve is setting a binding in the main window's xaml between one of its viewmodel's custom property and one of the usercontrol's viewmodel's custom property.

How would one go about doing that?

Comment: You should avoid having your view connect 2 VM. Views are meant to be disconnected as much as possible in MVVM. If you can access the child VM in the parent VM, Keep the properties in sync via the parent VM or use something like the Messenger from MVVM light to communicate between 2 independant VM's

Answer (score 1):

Could you instead use the ViewModels as projections of a Model?

That is, could you have a class that holds the state (or actions) that both the VMs need to expose and have both the VMs reference this class?

If for some reason you *have* to couple views to something outside their own DataContext I believe you can only go *up* the visual tree by using RelativeSource FindAncestor in the binding. I don't think you can traverse *down* (e.g. Window -> Control).

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to **Bind them together** you could make your ViewModel's properties [Dependency Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property) and your ViewModel derive from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) -  then you could do..

```
 var binding = new Binding("Something");
 binding.Source = myViewModel1;
 binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(viewModel2,ViewModelType.SomethingProperty,binding);
```

***If this is a good design having your viewmodels derive from DependencyObject is another question..***

You could also try looking at [this library](http://truss.codeplex.com/) that allows binding to and from POCOs.

Comment: This is a really bad idea for several reasons discussed [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)

Comment: @HighCore - that was the article i was trying to find when posting this, i read that myself when trying to make that very decision, good find

Comment: @HighCore, that link appears to be dead, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using a modelview for my usercontrol, not as neat but at least it works and is less complicated datacontext wise.
Thanks to all.